# Android encrypt util class, make singleton or not

Tags: android, amazon-s3

I have an android app which encrypts and uploads various files to AWS. The boiler plate code for AWS is a singleton, and I use that throughout my app. I have an encryption class as well, and I am currently instantiating encryption objects in various places, encrypting the file, and passing it to the singleton instance of the AWS upload class.

I am wondering if this is the best approach? Should i make the instance of the encryption object static? And have just one instantiated, and then call the encrypt method from different classes? In some places it is recommended, in others people say using static can be dangerous? Or is there a better way than either of these options?

Should note the app works fine as is, but I am a self taught Android dev, and I am trying to get better, but none of the tutorials go into heaps of detail about things like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static is not dangerous, it's to share operations that don't depend on instances of objects. Like the Math class.

Singleton pattern is for controlling instances of objetcs of some class. If you want an instance, and only one instance, you use singletons. Generally, people use it to get that instance at a global scope. I think the Application class would fit this.

I prefer to use dependency injection if I am working with a lot of service classes. Encryption is a service to me, but you have to do the mechanism for dependency injection, or use a framework, but this is overkill to your problem.

I would go for the static methods this time.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a Singleton class or making your object static, both are good options if you have to use the method of a class on various places. It's better to have a static object then creating the same object again and again.

So according to me the "Singleton" class is the best option to make your code efficient, but if you want to go with a static method/class then there is no harm in it. Static can be dangerous in some situations, like when you have to assign different values and get different values in different situations. Then there is a chance you can get wrong value in wrong situation. But in your case it's fine.